# Convert datetime with AM/PM to standard SQL server datetime

Tags: sql-server

I have a date in YYYYMMDDHHTT time format, how can I convert this to a 24-hour datetime (i.e. SQL server `DATETIME`)

Example: `201710031035AM`

Desired: `2017-10-03 10:35:00.000`

Comment: Can you provide some context for what you're trying to do? An example of what you've tried and any errors or wrong results you're seeing would go a long way towards getting others to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split up and concatenate the old string format so that SQL can recognize it as a date string

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING(oldFormat, 5, 2), ' ', 
    SUBSTRING(oldFormat, 7, 2), ' ', 
    SUBSTRING(oldFormat, 1, 4), ' ',
    SUBSTRING(oldFormat, 9, 2), ':',
    SUBSTRING(oldFormat, 11, 4)
), 100)
```

Where `100` is the datetime format 'mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)'. Or you can split up the datetime parts, and then pass then through the `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` function as ints. Just make sure that all of the old values are consistently formated first!

Comment: This is what I had in mind, just hoping there was a more eloquent solution.

Comment: The string formats SQL Server recognizes is pretty limited: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Just went with DATETIMEFROMPARTS